# Why teleportation isn't the primary intra-ship transport mechanism?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-transporter, teleportation

As it seems to be possible to teleport people between two parts of the ship (e.g. TNG: Gambit, Part II), why the Transporter, instead of the Turbolift, isn't the primary mechanism to transport people to different parts of the starship?

Comment: I would assume the turbolift uses much less energy than the transporter.

Comment: “And here I am using my legs like a sucker!” *-Homer Simpson* http://i.imgur.com/UlAbClM.png

Comment: @Stan And when the turbolift fails, it probably leaves people stranded in it, instead of disintegrating the passengers like a transporter failure.

Comment: Note that on DS9 it does seem to be used, to some extent, for intra-station travel.

Comment: Have you ever teleported? It's like jetlag on steroids!

Comment: Probably for the same reasons people today don't drive around in indoor cars.

Comment: Also, people in the Federation aren't hell-bent on being as lazy as possible.

Answer (score 46):

#### Because it isn't necessary. Intraship transport is relegated to medical and security emergencies. There are a limited number of transporters available and such energy is more vital to other services on the ship such as shields or the warp engines.

- Despite the relative abundance of energy in the Federation universe, it still costs energy to convert people into energy and restore them upon arrival. Since this energy comes from the warp engines and depletes dilithium it is unlikely such a use of energy would be conducive to good operational procedure except in emergencies.
- The turbolift is a far more energy effective means of moving crew members, equipment and visitors around the ship using a fraction of the energy of the transporter. During an emergency without warp power, there would be NO means of getting around the ship quickly except for transporters which could be taken out by enemy fire, power outages, or other emergencies.
- From a health and psychological perspective, walking is good for the crew, keeps them fit and healthy. Moving through the ship promotes good relationships and interactions between the crew.

Comment: Not to mention: Would YOU want to transport across the ship throughout the day, knowing how many transporter malfunctions happen in each series?

Comment: I'm not sure about the health reason, they exercise for recreation (including the holodecks) after all.

Comment: Also, what evidence do you have that turbolifts use less energy than tranporters?

Comment: @Richard common sense. A turbolift is a fancy elevator. Converting someone's matter into energy, transmitting it, and converting back is clearly going to cost more.

Comment: It's an elevator. I am absolutely certain despite the apparent ease at which transporters perform their magic, nothing is less energy-intensive than a magnetically-managed elevator system in the 23rd century.

Comment: Portable transporter units like the prototype site-to-site personal emergency transport unit that Data puts on Picard at the end of Nemesis was pretty darn small.  Probably did not carry anywhere near warp-coil levels of energy.  Probably.  Sure battery technology is better in the future, or maybe it harnesses some external energy field, ugh nevermind.

Comment: And as I recall the TNG Technical Manual (canon?) the pattern buffers have a significant cooldown time that limits the overall capacity of the transporter system and it **doubles** for site-to-site transport.

Comment: In addition to @Izkata's point, in the Enterprise era people were generally afraid to put themselves through transporters at all (an attitude that still existed into the TNG era, but was **much** less common to the point of surprising characters when encountered). And site-to-site didn't exist, anyway. So that covers pre-TOS, as well. :)

Comment: Because you can't stop the transporter halfway for a private chat. Plot device, nothing more.

Comment: In addition to massive energy use, risk from transporter malfunction, add Workplace Health & Safety Guidelines! -The dedicated transporter room is highly regulated precisely in order to minimize risk of operator error i.e. merging your feet with the ship schnauzer during rematerialization.

Comment: A [transporter](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55210/how-much-energy-does-the-transporting-of-one-person-consume) consumes almost no energy at all. If you assume an energy-consumption of W=m*g*h for the lift, the transporter will definitively beat that!

Comment: @Einer:The transporter has to convert the person into pure energy. E = mc^2.  c^2 is definitely bigger than gh probably by at least 10^13 if doing intra-ship transporting.

Comment: @Dunk Right, but all that energy of mc^2 is taken from the body-mass and needs to be reconverted into named body-mass. So in the balance we can safely ignore that. So the differnece between lift v/s transporter is `+mc^2-mc^2+37 MeV` v/s `mgh` or approximated (since in this dimensions 37MeV is almost nothing) `mgh`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20274/discussion-on-answer-by-thaddeus-star-trek-why-teleportation-isnt-the-primary).

Comment: **<comments removed>** I've cleaned up the comments a bit to remove the really tangential stuff.  Please keep it to discussing issues/questions on this answer.  Otherwise, [take it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20274/discussion-on-answer-by-thaddeus-star-trek-why-teleportation-isnt-the-primary).

Comment: That CGI transporter effect is way more pricey than a turbolift set, which can be reused.

Comment: @Zibbobz  -Geordi comments to Barclay that there have been only a handful of transporter accidents in the last decade, despite near-ubiquitous use of transporters in the Federation (millions of transports per year).

Answer (score 22):

**Starfleet vessels are just too small to merit the expenditure of energy on site-to-site transporters when simple turbolifts are sufficient.**

Star Trek production illustrator Doug Drexler, when discussing the next (next) generation of Starfleet vessels identified that [the Enterprise-J](http://web.archive.org/web/20120619002809/http://drexfiles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/enterprise-j-search/) would use transporters as the primary method of moving people around. He notes that this is due to the sheer **size** of the vessel:

> "as a multi-generational vessel, that had large parks, entertainment
>   zones, and entire universities on board. **The ship is so large that
>   turbolifts would be replaced with site to site transporters.** [It] had
>   one deflector, recognizably descended from the NX. I opted for spindly
>   nacelle struts because I felt it suggested a technology beyond what we
>   were familiar with. They are beyond transwarp. They can fold space,
>   and they are exploring other galaxies besides the Milky Way."

Also, based on this conversation in the Star Trek pilot, it's pretty clear that although the technology has been ubiquitous for nearly a century, not everyone likes being transported.

> **DATA'S VOICE :** *But, sir, the transporter could have you on the Hood in a matter of seconds, Admiral.*
>
> Data and the admiral ENTER SCENE at the intersection. The admiral is
>   very old with an almost transparent look.
>
> **ADMIRAL :** *Have you got some reason to want my atoms scattered all over space?*

Dr Pulaski shows a similar concern in TNG: Unnatural Selection as does Reginald Barclay in TNG: Realm of Fear, etc. It's hardly fair to expect officers to simply lump it that they'll have to be transported dozens of times a day.

---

Out of universe, the aim was to preserve as much of the "look" of the original Star Trek while allowing for *evolution* of the technology rather than outright revolution.

There were also production considerations;

> The fact that **Gene Roddenberry liked the concept of having discussions
>   in the turbolifts** of the Galaxy-class Enterprise influenced the
>   designers of the ship, who at first considered having an on-bridge
>   transporter for TNG, to ultimately discard that idea. <sub><sup>(Starlog issue #125, p. 46)</sup></sub>

Comment: Re the (now deleted) Answer about energy budgets being nonsense. This was an apt comment and modifies every Answer already offered. Given the extent and use of the Holodeck, with TNG fwd, one can hardly argue consistently about hypothetical "energy budgets" constraining intra-ship Transporter use. The real answer, the only answer, is *Roddenberry*.

Comment: @user23715 - For the record, the holodeck has its own power supply.

Comment: For the record, the Transporter Pad can be powered by a Hand Phaser. *Just say'n...*

Comment: @user23715 You're referring to [The Hunted](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Hunted_%28episode%29#Act_Four). Given that a Type II phaser can disintegrate multiple humanoids, and a phaser on overload can do considerable damage, that seems about right.

Comment: People seem to be conflating the *volume* required to store energy with the *amount* of energy that's available. Sure, a phaser packs a tremendous amount of energy, but the ship isn't stuffed full of phasers. Even in today's society, most people are not this wasteful - they'll walk rather than drive for 1 block. *Some* people might drive, but those people are probably not "starfleet material".

Comment: I have serious problems with the depiction of the transporter in The Hunted anyway. Apparently you can just flex your way out of being transported. *"During the attempted transport from the Enterprise's brig to the Angosian police transport vessel, Danar literally breaks out of the transporter beam, causing an explosion of energy within the cell that knocks Worf and Troi unconscious"*

Comment: "dear God his head is on backwards!!" "Why didn't anyone tell me I had such a big ass?!"

Answer (score 6):

From my [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5590/1148) on [In Star Trek - What's the Point of the Transporter Room?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5589/in-star-trek-whats-the-point-of-the-transporter-room/)

Originally, transporter beams only faced outwards, so you had to use a transporter room to beam out. Then they started pointing them inwards, but had issues with safety (such as materializing inside a bulkhead).

By the time we get to TNG, these technical issues have been overcome, but there is a large energy requirement for beaming. If the entire population of the Enterprise D (1000+) were transporting everywhere they went, it would consume a lot of energy. Furthermore, there likely are not enough transporter beam emitters facing inwards to satisfy the volume of transports that would be used in a a regular commute with-in the ship and recreation.

It is typically in emergency situations that you see people using site-to-site transports (such as to sick bay).

From the dubious [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transporter_(Star_Trek))

> A possible explanation for this is put forward in the Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Technical Manual, where such site-to-site transports would probably use twice as much energy as would be required for transport to or from the transporter room itself

Site-to-site transporting costs twice as much energy as just going to the transporter room. Therefore, if you have to walk to the transporter room, you might as well take the turbolift to 10-Forward.

Answer (score 1):

**Transporter Operator**

One important answer that was missed here is personnel. In every incarnation of Star Trek there is a Transporter Operator. Whatever the technological advancement, automated transport by the computer was a rarity (though it certainly did happen; nevertheless, often in "Emergency Transport" situations there was still an operator).

If we assume they weren't wasting the personnel on unnecessary transporter supervision, then the Transporter Operator performed some essential function in supervising the transport and making sure it was executed properly.

This, more than anything else, would make it prohibitive to use transporter technology for intraship transportation.

Comment: On numerous occasions, it's shown that the ship is capable of automated transport. It's not preferred, but is possible.

Comment: Certainly, Richard. I noted as much. However, if the automation was truly reliable there would be no need for a sentient operator, the computer could be trusted. Put another way, Starfleet doesn't have Turbolift operators, they are a trusted and reliable technology.

Comment: A computer would definitely have much more trouble moving its two fingers upwards in a sliding motion. (not disagreeing with you, just saying they never really made it impressive the actual importance of a human operator)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest it's because as a general rule, transport while at warp is prohibited.  As you would need to navigate the ship at any time - and whilst walking the corridors, have limited knowledge of whether you're at warp or not - it would likely be an established practice to just use the turbolifts.

STTNG S2 Ep 6 The Schizoid Man and STDS9 S2 Ep 15 Paradise being (possible) examples?

This theory supported by this line at Memory Alpha

> "Except in cases of extreme emergency, **protocols prohibited
>   transporting objects while traveling at warp speed**".

Comment: This doesn't apply to transports within the same warp bubble, only to transports outside it. It's presumably the same constraint that prevents you using phasers at warp.

Answer (score -1):

Another likely reason they didn't use the transporter for intraship transport is because of the risks involved. As mentioned on http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transporter#Transporter_accidents, There has been at least a dozen incidents with the transporters, some of which with lethal consequences, and that's just on the handful of ships we see in the shows and movies. Meanwhile, the turbolift (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Turbolift#Turbolift_incidents) has only had a handful of incidents, and none of them had deadly consequences.

Comment: Geordi tells Barclay that transporting is the safest method of travel with a vanishingly small number of incidents per million transports.

Comment: @Richard He's talking about long-distance transport. the Turbolift has far fewer casualties even, but isn't suited for long-distance travel due to requiring existing infrastructure.

Comment: Based on what we see in the show, turbolifts seem quite dangerous too :-)

Comment: @Richard have you checked my sources? from what I can tell from the wiki, there have been far more incidents involving the transporter than involving the turbolift. Also, where does Geordi tell Barclay that?

Comment: TNG [Realm of Fear](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/228.txt); **"GEORDI:** *How many Transporter accidents
have there been in the last ten years, Reg? Two... three? What about the millions of people who transport every day without a problem?"* - *"Transporting really is the safest way to travel, Reg."*

Comment: @Richard Wasn't that the same episode where Transporter Psychosis was introduced?